# Hibernate JPA @OneToOne Bidirectional Not Working in Spring-Boot

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, one-to-one

I have Two entities User and Cart with Bidirectional Mapping.

when I use a controller to save and Access the entities, I am getting the reference as null.

I have used mappedBy on cart but it gives user as null

User.Java

```
@Entity
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

private String name;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Cart cart;

//getters and setters and constructor

}
```

Cart.java

```
@Entity
public class Cart {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "cart", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private User user;

private String cnameString;

//getters and setters and constructor

}
```

controller.java

```
@RestController
public class MainCOntroller {

@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
CartRepository cartRepository;

@GetMapping("/")
public void str() {

    Cart cart = new Cart("AnonymousCart");
    cartRepository.saveAndFlush(cart);

    User user = new User("Anonymous", cart);
    userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);

    System.out.println(user + "\n" + cart);
  }
}
```

on hitting localhost:8080

the output is this:-

```
User [id=1, name=Anonymous, cart=Cart [id=1, user=null, 
cnameString=AnonymousCart]]
Cart [id=1, user=null, cnameString=AnonymousCart]
```

Not sure where I am going Wrong.

Comment: What happens if you add this assignment: `cart = cartRepository.save`...?

Comment: Nope, Did not change the output

Comment: Huh. This should work fine, since `User` is the owning side. The bidirectional relationship is often a pain in JPA (I wrote [a small library for Groovy](https://github.com/chrylis/groovybeans-toolkit) to handle exactly this, but it's unfortunately not available from Java). Since you're already cascading, I would next suggest saving only the User, although hold on--I don't see a `@Transactional` annotation anywhere. How are you managing that? Managed entities (your `cart`) are only valid within a particular context, and I don't see where you're opening one.

Comment: @chrylis the user is not set on the cart. Both sides have to be maintained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) saveAndFlush() returns the entity that if merge is called on the EntityManager must be used.

2) You must maintain both sides of the relationship and I don't see that you are assigning the user to the cart.

The correct code would look like:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public void str() {

    Cart cart = new Cart("AnonymousCart");

    // Use the returned cart
    cart = cartRepository.saveAndFlush(cart);

    User user = new User("Anonymous", cart);

    // Use the returned user
    user = userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);

    // assign the user to the cart
    cart.setUser(user);

    System.out.println(user + "\n" + cart);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Simon Martinelli that worked (gave overflow error but that was fixed by modifying the toString() of the user Entity).
But the last line "cart.setUser(user)", Doesn't that relation vanish on program restart as we aren't saviing this relation anywhere (Because it is already mapped by User). Then what is the use of Bidirectional Relations. Sorry if this is a newb Question.

Comment: can you please elaborate if the relation will be saved somewhere and not be lost on program restart

Comment: Sure if it's once saved to the database Hibernate will load both sides and set the references.

Comment: Sorry to bug you again and again but didn't we set the last reference after saving to the database, can you point me to a source where I can learn all these. Thank you again

Comment: Simply read the docs https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html